# Can we perform capacity planning in Azure Devops board based on Story points entered on User Stories instead on hours entered in Task?

Tags: task, user-stories, burndowncharts, capacity-planning

I want to know whether I can perform capacity planning based on story points entered in User Stories and not based on hours entered in Task. This way I don't have to define hours in task. I will just enter task under each User Story and leave the planning fields blank in Task.

Also, I want to understand whether I can generate Burn Down chart purely on the basis of story Points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can**:

- Use the Stories Backlog for Analytics, which will present burndown in Story Points
- View the Point load on the Sprint, while on the Sprint board, select the menu item "view options", select "Side Pane" = Planning, this will display points aggregated for each sprint
- Use Velocity charts to map your story points across sprints to train your team on Story Pointing and Team Capacity

**Cannot**:

- Use Story Points in capacity